# Dynamically checking and unchecking a task tree

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cakephp

I'm having issues making a task tree I have dynamically check boxes. Basically if a top level (parent task) is checked, I would like it to check all of the subtasks (child boxes). I have this working on one of my task trees, but for some reason can't get it to work for my other.

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup( { cache: false } );
    $('.task-tree').tree({
        ui: {
            theme_name: 'checkbox'
        },
        plugins : {
            checkbox: { three_state: false }
        },
        callback: {
            onload: function( tree ) {
                tree.open_all();
                $('.task-tree li a').each( function() {
                    var taskID = GetIdNum( $(this).attr('id') );
                    if ( $('#Task' + taskID + 'Enabled').val() == 1 )
                    {
                        console.log( $(this).parent() );
                        jQuery.tree.plugins.checkbox.check( $(this).parent() );
                    }
                });
            },
            onchange: function( node, tree ) {
                var selectedID = GetIdNum( $(node).find('a').attr('id') );
                var required = $('#Task' + selectedID + 'Required').val();
                console.log( 'REQ --> ' + required );

                if ( required == 1 )
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {                   
                    $('.task-tree li a').each( function() {
                        var taskID = GetIdNum( $(this).attr('id') );
                        console.log( taskID );
                        $('#Task' + taskID + 'Enabled').val(1);
                    });
                    console.log( '----------------------------------------------' );

                    var unchecked = jQuery.tree.plugins.checkbox.get_unchecked(tree).find('a.not-required');
                    $(unchecked).each( function(){
                        var taskID = GetIdNum( $(this).attr('id') );
                        console.log( taskID );
                        $('#Task' + taskID + 'Enabled').val(0);
                    });     
                    console.log( '*************************************************' );
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Let me know if you need any more info about the problem.

Comment: there's a jquery plugin for this, but the name escapes me.

Comment: Is that last javascript thing the plugin you are referring to? $javascript->link( 'jquery/jquery.hotkeys', false ); $javascript->link( 'jquery/jquery.cookie', false ); $javascript->link( 'jquery/sarissa', false ); $javascript->link( 'jquery/jquery.tree', false ); $javascript->link( 'jquery/plugins/jquery.tree.checkbox', false );

Comment: Does the other task tree have the right CSS class specified?